# HAProxy - Serving a URL from 2nd machine if the 1st returns a 404

Tags: haproxy

I have a situation where I have part of a website (certain URL paths) being served from one backend server while all other URLs are being served from a different default backend in HAProxy.

Now, because of the way the application logic was written, the files to be served under the same URL path could be created at the same path on either of the two physical server machines. I would like to be able to serve these files regardless of which machine the file exists on. So in a nutshell, how can I forward the request to one backend and if the response is a 404 (the file does not exist there), forward the request to be served from the other backend?

I am a complete noob to HAProxy so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

The relevant portions of my `haproxy.conf`:

`frontend frontend0
    ...
    acl de path_beg /path1
    acl de path_beg /path2
    acl de path_beg /path3
    use backend backend1 if de
    default_backend bakend
backend backend1
    ...
    server server_name 127.0.0.1:8000
backend backend2
    ...
    server server_name 192.168.11.1:8000`

There is a path `/path4` that needs to be served from both of these machines depending on where the file exists.

Comment: HAProxy releases the request buffer containing the headers as soon as the request is sent to the backend, so it has no way to retry a request elsewhere.  A hackaround I've used with success is to change 404 to 302 with a query string parameter so that the browser has to make a second request, and when the proxy sees that parameter, it tries the other server... but a better solution seems to be varnish behind HAProxy, since varnish does support restarting a request somewhere else.  Would you want to see either of those solutions?

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot. I'd be interested in both these solutions. The redirect solution is what I'd go with first since I've never used Varnish before but I'm willing to check it out. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'll have to find working examples, so it may take a few hours, but I'll see what I can put together.

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers in the documentation will also be much appreciated.

Comment: Using [`http-response`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#4-http-response) directives `set-status` and `set-header` is the core of the first option, if you want to take a stab at it before I can create some examples.  It turns out you don't have to worry about the 404 body, because browsers throw it away, just change the code to 302 and redirect to a modified version of the source URI.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Michael-sqlbot for the hint and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/807642/haproxy-1-6-redirect-using-http-response-map-and-regsub) question on ServerFault for the outline of the answer. The setup I finally ended up using is as follows:

- I setup a separate URL /_path4 that is served from one backend while the original URL /path4 is served from the other backend.
- On receiving a 404 response from the first backend for /path4, I redirect to the URL /_path4

My configuration file now looks as follows:

`frontend frontend0
    ...
    acl de path_beg /path1
    acl de path_beg /path2
    acl de path_beg /path3
    acl de path_beg /_path4
    use_backend backend2 if de
    default_backend backend1
    ...
backend backend1
    ...
    http-request set-var(txn.path) path
    server server_name 127.0.0.1:8000
    http-response redirect location %[var(txn.path),regsub('^/path4','/_path4')] code 303 if { status 404 } { var(txn.path) -m beg '/path4' }
    ...
backend backend2
    ...
    server server_name 192.168.11.1:8000`

As explained in @Michael-sqlbot's excellent comments to the linked question, the setting of a transaction variable is required because at the `http-response` stage, the buffer has been released and so the normal `path` variable used in the frontend is not available.